# Update query with compare of date and time

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query to update some field on some condition.

Conditions

> The time difference is not more than 1 hour and the date can be same.

```
select *
from Table
where user_cd = 'HARSHIT'
    and to_char(sysdate, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_char(brth_dt, 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

But one condition is also there like at night the user tries to update at 23:30 and after that the he tries next day at 00:15 so the difference is 45 min but the update must execute

```
select brth_dt from Table where user_cd = 'HARSHIT';

select sysdate from dual;

select brth_dt from Table
where user_cd = 'HARSHIT' 
  and sysdate-(1/24) < BRTH_DT;
```

Result of above query

### BRTH_DT

25/02/2016 12:30:00

1 row selected.

### SYSDATE

24/02/2016 16:7:58

1 row selected.

### BRTH_DT

25/02/2016 12:30:00

1 row selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no reason to convert a date to a string ... if you need to check 2 dates are within an hour of each other, just do the math on the date, and compare :

```
select * from sir_people 
where user_cd = 'HARSHIT' 
  and BRTH_DT BETWEEN sysdate-(1/24)
                  AND sysdate;
```

to_char on a date, for purposes of comparisons, is fundamentally flawed logic and should be avoided.

[edit] based on example provided: it appears you want to exclude future dates, and only include those dates between now, and an hour earlier.
query updated to accomodate that additional requirement.

Comment: if you are at `Feb 24, 2016 00:10:00` and want to check for dates 1 hour in past, then you subtract 1 hour from that DATE .. to get: `Feb 23, 2016 23:10:00` ... (ie sysdate-(1/24)), and then compare for anything greater than that (ie: `BRTH_DT > sysdate-(1/24)`) ... so yes, it will pull dates within 1 hour of current.  If you gave a more complete sample data, etc, it would be easier to show. ;)

Comment: hi it is not working for date.. Like if the date is 25/02/2016 and system date is 24/02/2016 then it should  not work But from your query it is working.

see the date1 = 24/02/2015 08:40:00
and date2 =  25/02/2015 08:40:00

both are in 24 hour format it should not work but by your query it is working only..

Comment: Please post a full example including sample data, and what you expect to see in your original post.  you keep changing names in there, so I have no idea if date1 is same as sysdate, in your original example, or date2 is ... (if date2 is same as sysdate, it will absolutely work - it will not pull it since it is beyond an hour in the past. if date1 is same as sysdate, then you are comparing current date with future dates, and I have no idea what you're trying to do) .. please, full sample data so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
to_char(col_name, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

just use 24-hour format, I think that should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply translate required condition into sql:
"The time difference is not more than 1 hour and the date can be same."

```
select *
  from Table
  where user_cd = 'HARSHIT'
        and abs(sysdate-brth_dt) <= 1/24
```

Comment: hi
I didn't got anything
0.0416666666666667  value of 1/24
0.444606481481481  value of sysdate-brth_dt

Comment: The difference 0.444606481481481 between sysdate and brth_dt is in days. When you multiple it by 24, you get more than 10 hours. It should not select, am I right? Maybe I don't understand you right.